# Javascript API issue

Tags: javascript, json, moltin

I currently have this

```
<option ng-id="1186384773090640435" value="1186384956868264500">Product Name</option>
```

I need to take both id and value and insert it into this below:

```
moltin.Cart.Insert($scope.productId, qty, { "1186384773090640435" : { "1186384956868264500" : 1} }, function (cart) {
```

How do I do this?

I am currently doing something like this at the moment but it doesnt work:

```
modi = $(this).attr('ng-id');
vari = $(this).attr('value');

moltin.Cart.Insert($scope.productId, qty, { modi : { vari : 1} }, function (cart) {
```

I can assume its because the values are not strings or objects. Not quite sure.

Comment: Use console.log to show the values of `modi` and `vari` after you set them.

Comment: You can use Chrome developpers tools and activate the debugger to break on javascript errors

Comment: You are doing it wrong, controller don't know the view, it's the first rule in angular.
You should have to add `ng-change='somethingChanged($event)'` on the select in the view
And in you controller : a `$scope.somethingChanged = function(event) {}` dans do the stuff inside. 
Another thing, normally if you have correctly generated your options you should have used `ng-options` dans the value of the option should be and object that you can retrieve automatically from ng-model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use variable values as object attribute names when creating object literals (except if you are writing ES20015). You will need something like :

```
modi = $(this).attr('ng-id');
vari = $(this).attr('value');
((insert = {})[modi] = {})[vari] = 1

moltin.Cart.Insert ($scope.productId, qty, insert, function ( ...
```

Explanation:

In the third line we first set a variable named `insert` to an empty object `(insert = {})`. To that object we add an attribute whose name is the value of variable `modi` and whose value is an empty object : `( ...[modi] = {})`. That empty object is in turn given an attribute whose name is the value of `vari` and whose value is 1. The whole expression returns the value 1 which explains why we need to set a variable name to reference the first created object.

Javascript so so accomodating ;-)

or (in three lines an only one var) :

```
let insert = {};
(insert[$(this).attr('ng-id')] = {})[$(this).attr('value')] = 1
moltin.Cart.Insert ($scope.productId, qty, insert, function ( ...
```

In ES2015 (ES6) this you can code this directly as :

```
moltin.Cart.Insert ($scope.productId, qty, {[modi]: {[vari]: 1}}, function ( ...
```

Comment: Tried the first example and it worked a treat. Many thanks. Would it be possible to explain what is going on here??